# Golang JSON Unmarshal to field, but NOT marshal into JSON response

Tags: json, go

I want to be able to access a struct field that's resulted from a JSON unmarshal, BUT I want to use that same struct to hide the field when it is marshaled.

Example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    GoodField string `json:"goodField"`
    SecretField string `json:"secret"`
}
```

Incoming JSON gets unmarshaled and the `secret` field is accessible
Use the same `MyStruct` in the server response but *hide* the `secret` field.

I've looked at using `omitempty` and `-` tags, not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were on the right track with `omitempty` you just have to set `SecretField` to `""` for it to take effect

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    GoodField string `json:"goodField"`
    SecretField string `json:"secret,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    data := MyStruct{}

    s := `{"goodField": "xxx", "secret": "yyy"}`

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &data);

    fmt.Println(data.GoodField, data.SecretField);

    data.SecretField = ""

    response, _ := json.Marshal(data)

    fmt.Println(string(response))

}
```

Comment: wow, I did not think of that! Just have to "reset" the field once I'm done with it.. and then omitempty would just take place as usual... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general I think the best pattern is to use separate request and response types, rather than mutating data just to prevent it from being marshaled; that's an intrusive and destructive approach, and the side-effect could bite you. In line with the Go proverb "a little duplication is better than a little dependency," you're better off just separating those concerns rather than try to have one type serve double duty.

If you want, though, you can try using struct embedding to DRY out the field declarations. With a combination of `omitempty` and `-` `json` tags, you can get the desired results:

```
type payload struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b,omitempty"`
}

type request struct {
    payload
}

type response struct {
    payload
    B string `json:"-"`
}
```

Here's a [worked example](https://play.golang.org/p/OdOJlMvoMcy) of the above.

It's not without its own issues to be aware of -- there are two fields named `B` here, not one. It works fine if you're just using dot-operator field access as in my example. If you use struct literals, you've got to be careful not to put the value in the wrong spot. Probably a good idea to write constructors for these types, to centralize that concern in one spot and get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you need this field accessible only from this package (which helps you to control access to it at all) you can make it *unexported* with first lowercase letter. Use this structure for all operations, except Marshalling/unmarshalling.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    GoodField string `json:"goodField"`
    secretField string `json:"secret"`
}
```

And make one more structure what will be used only for Marshalling.

Comment: I've discovered this feature as well, however, because its not exported, the field will be ignored when unmarshalled. In my case, I needed access to the field, but not returned in the response.

Comment: Yes, you use this structure for all operation except un/marshal. For these operations use another analogue structure with exported field

Answer (score 0):

If you can't, or don't want, to set the field to empty, you can accomplish this with a custom marshaler, as well:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    GoodField   string `json:"goodField"`
    SecretField string `json:"secret"`
}

func (ms *MyStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type MyStructWithoutSecretFields struct {
        GoodField   string `json:"goodField"`
    }
    noSecrets := MyStructWithoutSecretFields{
        GoodField: ms.GoodField,
    }
    return json.Marshal(noSecrets)
}
```